# Message from one scene to another (not an overlay)

Tags: game-engine

Is it possible to send a message from one scene to another? According to the manual page, it should be possible if the object field is left blank. I have a collision sensor which sends a message when player hits a flag at the end of a level. I want to have another scene which charts my progress through the levels and adds a 'level complete' icon to the display.  However the message sensor I am using in the progress scene is not receiving anything. I have tried adding the progress scene as a background scene to the level scene and I can see the property I am using to check does change but is reset as soon as I enter the progress scene and the message is not received. I have also tried using a blank overlay scene in both scenes to track the message on an empty but no joy. Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 1):

I've done some tests and you can not send a message to a scene that did not loaded.

In the example 1 the scene1 send a message when mouseOver the scene2 recive the message and add  1 to count, i use a script to print the value.

**Scene 1 logic:**

[image]

**Scene 2 logic:**

```
from bge import logic

obj = logic.getCurrentScene().objects['Suzanne']
print(obj['count'])
```

[image]

**Behaviour when:**

**scene2 IS NOT an overlay nor background**

[image]

**scene2 IS overlay or background**

[image]

In the example 2 i dont use any message. I store the value in an attribute of bge.logic module.

**Scene 1 logic:**

```
from bge import logic

if not hasattr(logic, 'count'):
    logic.count = 0
else:
    logic.count += 1
```

[image]

**Scene 2 logic:**

```
from bge import logic

if hasattr(logic, 'count'):
    print(logic.count)
```

[image]

**Behaviour when:**

**scene2 IS NOT an overlay nor background**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. I thought the messages survive the scene switch (maybe they did in the past).

Comment: I just tested with 2.74 and it worked with message and set scene. ... the same file works with 2.79 too.

Comment: Yeah with set scene it work, but i understood from the question that the op want to send from scene1 a message to scene2 to add something in scene3 while you still in scene1. Not understood that will send a message from scene1 to scene2 and then load scene2. Maybe my bad english.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately I do not fully understand the description of the question. The title of the question seams not to describe the real business.